# Does res.end() ends async.waterfall?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, express

I have this code:

```
async.waterfall([
   function (callback){
       //some work
   },
   function (callback){
        if(something)
            res.status(200).send('Some message').end();
        else
            callback(null);
   },
   function (callback){
        //some work
   }
], function(err){
    //Do something here...
});
```

I wonder if I can do this:

```
res.status(200).send('Some message').end();
```

Will async ends or it will be waiting forever for a callback using resources from the machine? If yes, how to fix this because I have it all over my code and the way it is, is very clear to me and anything different I think would be confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will async ends or it will be waiting forever for a callback using resources from the machine?

Yes, in your middle worker function, you don't call the callback ever when `something` is true. In this case the response will be sent, but the `waterfall` will never complete. You can terminate the waterfall by calling the callback with a benign error meaning only "short circuit", or you can call it with a success value that also means short circuit (probably clearer).

```
async.waterfall([
   function (callback){
       //some work
   },
   function (callback){
        if(something)
            res.status(200).send('Some message').end();
            callback(null, true); //true means "short circuit"
        else
            callback(null);
   },
   function (shortCircuit, callback){
     if (shortCirtcuit) {
       callback(null, true);
       return;
      }
        //some work
   }
], function(err){
    //Do something here...
});
```

---

- Side note: `res.send('Some message');` Will do it. 200 is the default status and `send` implies `end`.